# Missing version history

Tags: document-library, version-history

I have a situation where a document has been published to the next major version but history is missing.  See screenshot, is there a way to view the history elsewhere and would have caused this?[image]

Comment: What is missing exactlty? The v1 of the file or the approval status?, ...

Comment: The approval status and any other changes that might have occurred in the metadata.